# copy and paste between workbooks without activating any of them

Tags: vba, excel

The following codes copies and pastes between different workbooks. I am not sure why it won't work without "Source.Activate" and "Master.Activate" lines? In other words, why is the activation of workbooks required despite the fact they were declared and set at the beginning?

```
Dim Source As Worksheet
Set Source = Workbooks("Source.xlsx").Worksheets("Settlements")
Dim Master As Worksheet
Set Master = Workbooks("Master.xlsm").Worksheets(Sheets.Count)

Source.Activate '???

For Each cell In Source.Columns("M").Cells
    If cell <> "" Then
        Master.Activate '???
            For Each cell2 In Master.Columns("J").Cells
                If cell2 <> "" Then
                    If cell = cell2 Then
                        cell2.Offset(0, 9).Value = cell.Offset(0, -2).Value
                        cell2.Offset(0, 8).Value = cell.Offset(0, -8).Value
                    End If
                End If
            Next cell2
     End If
Next cell
```

Thanks in advance,
Bartek

Comment: Shouldn't need to. Are you saying it doesn't work without the `Activate` lines? That looks very cumbersome though - you are looping through a million million cells.

Comment: Yes, it does not work without "Activate".

Comment: What happens? An error?

Comment: Yes, if for example I remove "Source.Activate", Source sheet has to be activated before executing first loop, otherwise an error appears.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: You **will** have a problem with your line `Set Master = Workbooks("Master.xlsm").Worksheets(Sheets.Count)` if `Master.xlsm` is not the active workbook (due to the unqualified `Sheets` reference) but I can't see any other reason for needing an `Activate`.

Comment: Thanks all, works now. BTW, the code is very slow, is it because it loops through every cell in a column to check if cell is empty? Does it use so much memory? If I use direct cell range references the macro is much faster, but I want to keep the code flexible in case of future workbook changes

Answer (score 1):

Neither the source nor the destination workbook has to be active to perform copy/paste.  For example:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim b1 As Workbook, b2 As Workbook
    Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range

    Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\TestFolder\1\1.xlsx"
    Set b1 = ActiveWorkbook
    Set r1 = b1.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")

    Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\TestFolder\1\2.xlsx"
    Set b2 = ActiveWorkbook
    Set r2 = b1.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")

    ThisWorkbook.Activate
    r1.Copy r2
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the activates at all or anything to do with active workbook.
But you do need to use match or find instead of looping through every cell in your master file.

The `Not IsError`, is to skip the non matches, since Match throws an error when it doesn't find a match.  The Match function returns the row number of the first match it finds.

One other thing `.Worksheets(Sheets.Count)` returns the last worksheet in the workbook, why not set this to a worksheet name like source is?

```
Dim Source As Worksheet
Dim Master As Worksheet
Set Source = Workbooks("Source.xlsx").Worksheets("Settlements")
Set Master = Workbooks("Master.xlsm").Worksheets(Sheets.Count)

For Each c In Source.Columns("M").Cells
    If c <> "" Then

                    If Not Application.WorksheetFunction.IsError(Application.Match(c, Master.Columns("J"), 0)) Then
                        crow = Application.Match(c, Master.Columns("J"), 0)
                         Master.Range("J" & crow).Offset(0, 9).Value = c.Offset(0, -2).Value
                         Master.Range("J" & crow).Offset(0, 8).Value = c.Offset(0, -8).Value
                    End If
                'End If
            'Next cell2
     End If
Next c
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use worksheet name before every cell that's defined; e.g.,

```
master.range(master.cells(1,2),master.cells(4,2)).copy
```

This worked for me.